# Viber Bot send files from Buffer

Tags: node.js, viber-api

I am trying to use viber-bot to send pdf files to a client, but I don't have these files locally or as a url.I get required files from other requests, and I haven't found anything about buffers in viber-bot documentation.
Here is my code:

```
const ViberBot = require('viber-bot').Bot,
  BotEvents = require('viber-bot').Events,
  TextMessage = require('viber-bot').Message.Text,
  FileMessage = require('viber-bot').Message.File,
  express = require('express');
const app = express();

if (!process.env.BOT_ACCOUNT_TOKEN) {
  console.log('Could not find bot account token key.');
  return;
}
if (!process.env.EXPOSE_URL) {
  console.log('Could not find exposing url');
  return;
}

const bot = new ViberBot({
  authToken: process.env.BOT_ACCOUNT_TOKEN,
  name: process.env.BOT_NAME,
  avatar: ''
});
bot.on(BotEvents.SUBSCRIBED, response => {
  response.send(new TextMessage(`Hi there ${response.userProfile.name}. I am ${bot.name}! Feel free to ask me anything.`));
});
bot.onSubscribe(response => console.log(`Subscribed: ${response.userProfile.name}`));
bot.on(BotEvents.MESSAGE_RECEIVED, async (message, response) => {
  try {
//use buffer instead of urls
    await response.send(
new FileMessage('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Katze_weiss.png', 2, 'test.png')).catch(err => console.log(err))
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  response.send(new TextMessage(`Message received.`));
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use("/viber/webhook", bot.middleware());
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Application running on port: ${port}`);
  bot.setWebhook(`${process.env.EXPOSE_URL}/viber/webhook`).catch(error => {
    console.log('Can not set webhook on following server. Is it running?');
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: @edrichhans it seems like Viber is not able to do such things

Answer (score 0):

What did the trick for me:

- Viber Bot runs on local server under Node.js
- Ngrok generates and exposes a specific link that takes ViberBot Live on internet.
- Generate your .pdf and save it on local path (e.x. ngrokpath/myfiles/mypdf.pdf)

Then inside your bot make use of:

```
var filename = "MyClientFile.pdf";
var urlstring = expose_url+"/myfiles/"+filename;    
var pdffilesize = 150; //kb                        
response.send(new FileMessage(urlstring, pdffilesize, filename));
```

expose_url is the url from Ngrok session.
pdffilesize is just for reference according viber api. Viber Bot needs to know filesize.

In case you don't want to have a local file stored and directly retrieved from buffer, use pdfmake plugin.

Generate your pdf (base64 string) and then feed to viber message as media.

Hope that works for you too...

[Ngrok Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrok)

[pdfmake tutorial](https://medium.com/@kainikhil/nodejs-how-to-generate-and-properly-serve-pdf-6835737d118e)